# Build filepaths from JSON file

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, tree, depth-first-search

so I'm running into an DFS problem where I'm trying to build a list of file paths from a JSON file (which is converted into a dict internally obviously).

I've tried a few different approaches all involving a recursive function call, but I'm not getting the desired results. On top of that, I'm having issue figuring out how I can add a way to store these nested hierarchies so they create the path for that parent.

In the end, I simply want a list of paths that will be used to generate directories.

For example, if I had the following JSON/dict:

```
input = [
{"root-folder": 
    {"parent":
        {"child": ["leaf", "node", "test"]},
    }
},
{"config-folder":
      {"user": ["test", "dev", "prod"]}
}
]
```

I would like to have the following directories created:

```
root-folder/parent/child/leaf
root-folder/parent/child/node
root-folder/parent/child/test

config-folder/user/test
config-folder/user/dev
config-folder/user/prod
```

The code I have down below isn't giving me the result I'm expecting:

```py
def build_hierarchy_path(directory_hierarchy):
    if isinstance(directory_hierarchy, list):
        for item in directory_hierarchy:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                build_hierarchy_path(item)
    elif isinstance(directory_hierarchy, dict):
        for key, value in directory_hierarchy.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                build_hierarchy_path(value)
            else:
                print(key, value)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

For the new case, we also need to account for strings. Here we treat strings as the end case and print them, while lists and dicts are passed back into the function:

```py
def build_hierarchy_path(directory_hierarchy, parent=None):
    if parent is None:
        for item in directory_hierarchy:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                build_hierarchy_path(item, Path(""))
    elif isinstance(directory_hierarchy, str):
        print(parent / directory_hierarchy)
    elif isinstance(directory_hierarchy, list):
        for item in directory_hierarchy:
            build_hierarchy_path(item, parent)
    elif isinstance(directory_hierarchy, dict):
        for key, value in directory_hierarchy.items():
            build_hierarchy_path(value, parent / key)
```

Which gives us:

```
root-folder\parent\child\temp-child\delete_me
root-folder\parent\child\leaf
root-folder\parent\child\node
root-folder\parent\child\test
config-folder\user\test
config-folder\user\dev
config-folder\user\prod
```

**Original answer:**

Thanks for providing an expected output here. You might find the `pathlib` package useful for working with directories.

To build on your code, I think we need to accumulate the previous segments of the path as we recursively iterate:

```py
def build_hierarchy_path(directory_hierarchy, parent=None):
    if parent is None:
        for item in directory_hierarchy:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                build_hierarchy_path(item, Path(""))
    elif isinstance(directory_hierarchy, dict):
        for key, value in directory_hierarchy.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                build_hierarchy_path(value, parent / key)
            else:
                for item in value:
                    print(parent / key / item)
```

In this example, we pass the parent path structure to the function. This should give us the whole paths in the printed output:

```
root-folder\parent\child\leaf
root-folder\parent\child\node
root-folder\parent\child\test
config-folder\user\test
config-folder\user\dev
config-folder\user\prod
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for the response! It does seem to be working now, however I'm running into the issue of having multiple nested hierarchies throwing a TypeError: ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'PosixPath' and 'dict'```. If you have a dict inside one of the children elements, say you want to have 1 of the folders to have a deeper hierarchy, this breaks the code. What I mean by that using your method, I can only have a list of directories in any parent directory, but none of those directories can have children themselves (represented as dicts).

Comment: If you add a dict as the first entry in the list  in any of the hierarchies, you should get the same error.

Comment: using this you will get this error I mentioned above

```python 
input= [
  {
    "root-folder": {
      "parent": {
        "child": [
          {"temp-child": "delete_me"},
          "leaf",
          "node",
          "test"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "config-folder": {
      "user": [
        "test",
        "dev",
        "prod"
      ]
    }
  }
]```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity to change your JSON structure, I would recommend using a more regular convention where directory contents are always arrays.  Entries in a directory can then be a simple string for a file name or a single-key dictionary for a subdirectory with their value expressed as a directory (i.e. an array).

This would allow directories to contain both files and subdirectories (which your current structure would have trouble with).

```
dirs = [
{"root-folder":[ 
    {"parent":[
        {"child": ["leaf", "node", "test"]},
        "File1",
        "File2"]
    }]
},
{"config-folder":[
      {"user": ["test", "dev", "prod"]},
      "File4",
      "File5"]
}
]
```

With this structure, the recursive extraction of paths can be done using a generator function:

```
def getPaths(structure):
    for item in structure:
        if isinstance(item,str):
            yield item
            continue
        for dirName,content in item.items():
            for subPath in getPaths(content):
                yield dirName+"\\"+subPath

for path in getPaths(dirs):
    print(path)

root-folder\parent\child\leaf
root-folder\parent\child\node
root-folder\parent\child\test
root-folder\parent\File1
root-folder\parent\File2
config-folder\user\test
config-folder\user\dev
config-folder\user\prod
config-folder\File4
config-folder\File5
```

If you can't change the structure of the JSON input, you will have to handle the inconsistency between the top level (list of dictionaries) and the branches (nested dictionaries) either with if/else statements or using separate functions.

Here's an example using two generator functions:

```
dirs = [
{"root-folder": 
    {"parent":
        {"child": ["leaf", "node", "test"]},
    }
},
{"config-folder":
      {"user": ["test", "dev", "prod"]}
}
]

def getPaths(structure):
    if isinstance(structure,list):
        for fileName in structure: yield fileName
    else:
        for dirName,content in structure.items():
            for subPath in getPaths(content):
                yield dirName+"\\"+subPath
                
def getPathList(roots):
    for rootDir in roots:
        for path in getPaths(rootDir):
            yield path

for path in getPathList(dirs):
    print(path)

root-folder\parent\child\leaf
root-folder\parent\child\node
root-folder\parent\child\test
config-folder\user\test
config-folder\user\dev
config-folder\user\prod
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call does not get information of the path you already walked.
Instead of printing within the function, I would propose to make your function a generator, so it just yields the paths. Then the caller can decide what to do with it: it can print the entries or do something else with it. This makes your function less tied to I/O.

Here is how you could do it:

```
def build_hierarchy_path(nested):
    if isinstance(nested, str):
        yield nested
    elif isinstance(nested, list):
        yield from (path
            for value in nested
            for path in build_hierarchy_path(value))
    elif isinstance(nested, dict):
        yield from (key + "/" + path 
            for key, value in nested.items() 
            for path in build_hierarchy_path(value))
    else:  # Probably a good idea to check for unexpected content
        raise ValueError("unexpected type", nested)
```

You can then call it as follows:

```
for path in build_hierarchy_path(structure):
    print(path)
```

The input can here be as simple as just a string: in that case the function yields that string:

```
print(*build_hierarchy_path("root"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a recursive function that can handle quite complex structures (nested directories within lists as well). The recursion stops when all entries in a list are strings. The output is a list of paths which can be further used to build the desired directory hierarchies.

#### Functions to retrieve directory paths:

```
# Helper functions
def sort_list_by_type(l):
    #
    strings = []
    dics = []
    
    for entry in l:
        if isinstance(entry, str):
            strings += [entry]
        elif isinstance(entry, dict):
            dics += [entry]
            
    return strings + dics

def build_paths(dic, root, paths):
    #
    for key,val in dic.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            root += f'{key}/'
            return build_paths(val, root, paths)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            val = sort_list_by_type(val)
            for item in val:
                if isinstance(item, str):
                    paths += f'{root}{key}/{item} '
                elif isinstance(item, dict):
                    root += f'{key}/'
                    return build_paths(item, root, paths)
    
    return paths


# Main
def get_paths(dic_list:'list of dictionaries'):
    #
    paths = ''
    for entry in dic_list:
        paths += build_paths(entry, '', '')

    return paths.split(' ')[:-1]
```

#### Examples

```
# Yours
inputs = [
    {"root-folder": 
     {"parent":
      {"child": ["leaf", "node", "test"]},
     }
    },
    {"config-folder":
     {"user": ["test", "dev", "prod"]}
    }
]

get_paths(inputs)
>>> ['root-folder/parent/child/leaf',
     'root-folder/parent/child/node',
     'root-folder/parent/child/test',
     'config-folder/user/test',
     'config-folder/user/dev',
     'config-folder/user/prod']


# Other (complex structures)
inputs = [
    {"root-folder": 
     {"parent":
      {"child": [
          "leaf", "node", "test",{'sub-child':
                                  {'templates':[
                                      'A',
                                      {'sub-templates':[
                                          '1','2',
                                          {'temporary':['a','b']}
                                      ]},
                                      'B'
                                  ]}
                                 },
          'etc'
      ]}
     }
    },
    {"config-folder":{"user": [
        "test", "dev", "prod"
    ]}
    }
]

get_paths(inputs)
>>> ['root-folder/parent/child/leaf',
     'root-folder/parent/child/node',
     'root-folder/parent/child/test',
     'root-folder/parent/child/etc',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/A',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/B',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/sub-templates/1',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/sub-templates/2',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/sub-templates/temporary/a',
     'root-folder/parent/child/sub-child/templates/sub-templates/temporary/b',
     'config-folder/user/test',
     'config-folder/user/dev',
     'config-folder/user/prod']
```

#### Combined with building directory hierarchies

```
import os

# Helper
def create_dirs(path):
    #
    build_path = '/'
    for parent in path.split('/'):
        build_path += f'{parent}/'
        if not os.path.exists(build_path):
            os.mkdir(build_path)

# Main
def build_directory_hierarchy(root_dir:'abs path (str), must exist!', list_dir:list):
    #
    if not os.path.exists(root_dir):
        raise ValueError("Root directory doesn't exist.")
    
    for dir_path in list_dir:
        dir_path = root_dir + dir_path if root_dir.endswith('/') else f'{root_dir}/{dir_path}'
        create_dirs(dir_path)


# Use case
build_directory_hierarchy('/PATH_TO_HOME/desktop/test', get_paths(inputs))
>>> "Directory hierarchy successfully created in 'test' folder."
```

Note: The root path to the working directory ('test' in the use case) needs to exist. Otherwise an error is raised.

Looking forward to critics or recommendations and gladly hear your comments about use cases.